# In which order `storage` event is received?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, local-storage, web-storage

In which order `storage` event is received?

For example, tab_1 executes code

```js
localStorage.set('key', 1);
localStorage.set('key', 2);
```

and tab_2 executes code

```js
localStorage.set('key', 3);
localStorage.set('key', 4);
```

They execute code simultaneously.

Questions:

- Can 2 be stored before 1?
- Can 3 or 4 be stored between 1 and 2?
- Can tab_3 receive `storage` events not in same order as values were stored in?(like if we stored 3, 4, 1, 2, can we receive 1, 2, 3, 4, or even in random order like 4, 1, 2, 3)

Comment: Well, first off localStorage is per domain, so the user would have to have the same site open in different tabs. Secondly, depending on browser, the tab that isn't focused isn't going to be running Javascript at all: Chrome at the very least throttles JS in background tabs to improve performance. Given the speed at which JS processes, it isn't generally humanly possible to interact with a page, switch to a different tab, and interact with the same site in that other tab fast enough to matter.

Comment: @JaredSmith Can you elaborate on this point `the tab that isn't focused isn't going to be running Javascript at all`, it contradicts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123373/javascript-can-javascript-run-while-a-browser-tab-is-not-in-focus

Comment: The accepted answer to that question is wrong: I can tell you from having built a minimal latency near-real-time dashboard that Google Chrome will not run e.g. setInterval code in background tabs. Firefox (last time I tested, which was years ago back when it still made sense to care about what Firefox does) did run JS in background tabs. Unless it is a blocking synchronous operation your code won't run in a background tab because as far as I can tell the event loop just doesn't tick in background tabs in Chrome. It's unclear why you're even worried about this.

Comment: @JaredSmith Code can definitely run in background. This code and page wouldn't be needed otherwise https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event

Comment: @JaredSmith Running this code `setInterval(() => console.log(new Date()), 1000)` in console and unfocusing tab is enough to see that it runs in background

Comment: Well it may have changed then, it was about 7 years ago last time I tested it. At any rate, it still isn't clear why you care about any of this.

Comment: @JaredSmith I have class `LocalStorageReactiveValueProvider`, which provides value for multiple tabs. I wrote it too complex, because I needed to guarantee order of events, and now I want to simplify it

Comment: @IvanIvanyuk ... if you _"need[...] to guarantee order of events"_ provide a timestamp to each to be stored item, or, even better, in case one anyhow handles events, make use of an event's timestamp for storing the related value.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Well, I use 2 fields for it, `currentTimestamp`, and `updateNumber`, because they allow to guarantee that as long as there are less than ~2^64 operations per timestamp precision, we will have correct version. It is the most robust solution, and not very complex, but complexity comes from handling deserialization/decryption errors, so I do want to simplify this logic a lot, but can't prove that I don't need this logic, hence tried asking here

Comment: "*Found answers*" - please [post an answer yourself](/help/self-answer) instead of editing the question

Comment: For "Can 3 or 4 be stored between 1 and 2?" the answer is actually yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already quoted in the previous answer, the specs say

> This specification does not define the interaction with other agent clusters in a multiprocess user agent, and authors are encouraged to assume that there is no locking mechanism.

Then, each `Document` will have its own `Storage` object set as its [local storage holder](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#local-storage-holder).
This `Storage` object is supposed to be a wrapper around a [storage proxy map](https://storage.spec.whatwg.org/#storage-proxy-map) which itself should act directly over its [backing map](https://storage.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-storage-proxy-map-backing-map) which is supposed to be directly the [storage bottle](https://storage.spec.whatwg.org/#storage-bottle)'s [map](https://storage.spec.whatwg.org/#bottle-map), i.e. where the data is actually stored, and thus this should be the same for all Documents.

So... that doesn't help much to know what should happen in case two same-origin Documents in two different agent clusters (and thus possibly running in parallel) would write to the same bucket at the same time.

All the specs say is that as an author you should not expect any locking mechanism.

So in your scenario, **according to the specs**,

> Can 2 be stored before 1?

It's a definitive no. [`setItem()`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#dom-storage-setitem) updates the map synchronously there is no way `2` would be set before `1` from the same agent.

> Can 3 or 4 be stored between 1 and 2?

Yes it can. If your *tab_1* is locked between these two lines there is nothing in the specs that prevents *tab_2* from writing to the same map.

> Can *tab_3* receive storage events not in same order as values were stored in?

[`setItem()`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#dom-storage-setitem) is responsible of [broadcasting](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#concept-storage-broadcast) the storage, which will queue a task on every [global object](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#concept-relevant-global) whose Document's `Storage`'s `map` will point to the same bottle's map, and in order to queue that task, it must use the one and only [DOM manipulation task source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-manipulation-task-source), so it's ensured that all the events will be fired in the order their respective tasks have been queued.

---

#### Now as to what implementations actually do, it seems a bit complex.

To test this, we need to have same-origin documents running in parallel. The best for it is to open separate browser windows (not just tabs) and navigate through a common origin from there. Then we can try to write to *tab_1*'s Storage, and begin a busy loop that will read the same key that it just set.
While *tab_1* is performing its busy loop, we can ask *tab_2* to also write to the same key as *tab_1* did. All this while listening to storage event in a *tab_3*.
If they were really updating the same map, we'd see the change during the busy loop in *tab_1*, or *tab_2* would have to somehow wait until *tab_1* is done with its busy loop.

I prepared these page tests:

- [tab_1](https://helix-ultra-traffic.glitch.me/tab_1.html),
- [tab_2](https://helix-ultra-traffic.glitch.me/tab_2.html),
- and [tab_3](https://helix-ultra-traffic.glitch.me/tab_3.html).

Please make sure they all run in their own agent cluster by checking that *tab_2*'s content is updated even while *tab_1* is busy (red background).

**tab_1**

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = async (evt) => {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"; // Make it visible when the page is locked
  log("begin test");
  await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 10));
  localStorage.test = "1";
  let a = localStorage.test;
  const t1 = performance.now();
  while(performance.now() - t1 < 3000) {
    if (a !== localStorage.test) { // Check whether the value has changed
      log("value changed during busy loop");
      a = localStorage.test;
    }
  }
  localStorage.test = "2";
  log("end test " + localStorage.test);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = null;
};
onstorage = ({ newValue, key }) => {
  log("received a new storage event");
  const currentValue = localStorage.getItem(key);
  log({ newValue, currentValue, key });
}
```

**tab_2**

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = async (evt) => {
  log("setting values");
  localStorage.test = "3";
  localStorage.test = "4";
  log("values set " + localStorage.test);
};
```

**tab_3**

```js
onstorage = ({ newValue, key, url }) => {
  log("received a new storage event");
  const currentValue = localStorage.getItem(key);
  log({ newValue, currentValue, key, url });
}
```

The actual results are a bit surprising. In Chrome we can see in *tab_3* that it received the first event from *tab_1*, then the 2 events from *tab_2*, and the last event from *tab_1* (`1`, `3`, `4`, `2`). So **this confirms the fact that `3` and `4` can be written in between `1` and `2`.** The surprising part is that *tab_1* didn't see the value change at all during its busy loop.
This would mean they don't actually update the main bottle's map, but just the wrapper or a local version of the map, and somehow wait on something to update the actual map or every local versions, even though this isn't in accordance with the specs. And while *tab_1* also receives the events from *tab_2*, in the next tasks, the stored value at the time it receives the event is actually `2` and not `4` like the event's `newValue` says it is.

In Firefox the behavior is yet a bit farther from the specs since they do apparently *broadcast* the storage only at the end of the task. So there in *tab_3*, we actually receive the two events from *tab_2*, and then the two events from *tab_1* (`3`, `4`, `1`, `2`).
**So the answer to your third question is actually also a yes...**

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript being single threaded (in the absence of Web Workers, who do not communicate through shared memory), the processing order within a browser tab is well defined.

As for ordering across tabs, the spec [cautions](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#introduction-15):

> The localStorage getter provides access to shared state. This specification does not define the interaction with other agent clusters in a multiprocess user agent, and authors are encouraged to assume that there is no locking mechanism. A site could, for instance, try to read the value of a key, increment its value, then write it back out, using the new value as a unique identifier for the session; if the site does this twice in two different browser windows at the same time, it might end up using the same "unique" identifier for both sessions, with potentially disastrous effects.

[HTML Spec Issue 403](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/403) requests that the concurrency behavior of `localStorage` be specified better, but a solution has yet to be defined at this time ...

**Implementation in Current Browsers**

If I open 3 browser windows for the same origin, and execute the following in each of them:

```
function test(increment) {
    let x = localStorage.test;
    console.log("polling for changes, initial value is", x);
    for (let i = 0; i < 50000000; i++) {
        let y = localStorage.test;
        if (x != y) {
            console.log("seeing new value", y);
            x = y;
        }
        if (i % 10000000 == 0) {
            let n = parseInt(x) + increment;
            console.log("setting new value", n);
            localStorage.test = n;
        }
    }
}
window.onstorage = e => console.log(
    `receiving storage event ${e.oldValue} -> ${e.newValue} while reading ${localStorage.test}`
);
```

And then in the first browser window:

```
localStorage.test = 0;
test(1);
```

and while that is executing, in the second browser window:

```
test(2);
```

Output in Chrome, first tab:

```
polling for changes, initial value is 0
setting new value 1
seeing new value 1
setting new value 2
seeing new value 2
setting new value 3
seeing new value 3
setting new value 4
seeing new value 4
setting new value 5
seeing new value 5
undefined
receiving storage event 1 -> 3 while reading 11
receiving storage event 2 -> 5 while reading 11
receiving storage event 3 -> 7 while reading 11
receiving storage event 4 -> 9 while reading 11
receiving storage event 5 -> 11 while reading 11
```

second tab

```
receiving storage event 0 -> 1 while reading 1
test(2);
polling for changes, initial value is 1
setting new value 3
seeing new value 3
setting new value 5
seeing new value 5
setting new value 7
seeing new value 7
setting new value 9
seeing new value 9
setting new value 11
seeing new value 11
undefined
receiving storage event 3 -> 2 while reading 11
receiving storage event 5 -> 3 while reading 11
receiving storage event 7 -> 4 while reading 11
receiving storage event 9 -> 5 while reading 11
```

third tab

```
receiving storage event 0 -> 1 while reading 1
receiving storage event 1 -> 3 while reading 3
receiving storage event 3 -> 2 while reading 2
receiving storage event 2 -> 5 while reading 5
receiving storage event 5 -> 3 while reading 3
receiving storage event 3 -> 7 while reading 7
receiving storage event 7 -> 4 while reading 4
receiving storage event 4 -> 9 while reading 9
receiving storage event 9 -> 5 while reading 5
receiving storage event 5 -> 11 while reading 11
```

Doing the same in current Firefox, we get:

```
polling for changes, initial value is 0
setting new value 1
seeing new value 1
setting new value 2
seeing new value 2
setting new value 3
seeing new value 3
setting new value 4
seeing new value 4
setting new value 5
seeing new value 5
undefined
receiving storage event 0 -> 2 while reading 10
receiving storage event 2 -> 4 while reading 10
receiving storage event 4 -> 6 while reading 10
receiving storage event 6 -> 8 while reading 10
receiving storage event 8 -> 10 while reading 10
```

second tab:

```
polling for changes, initial value is 0 
setting new value 2
seeing new value 2
setting new value 4
seeing new value 4
setting new value 6
seeing new value 6
setting new value 8
seeing new value 8
setting new value 10
seeing new value 10
receiving storage event 0 -> 1 while reading 10
receiving storage event 1 -> 2 while reading 10
receiving storage event 2 -> 3 while reading 10
receiving storage event 3 -> 4 while reading 10
receiving storage event 4 -> 5 while reading 10
undefined
```

third tab

```
receiving storage event 0 -> 1 while reading 5
receiving storage event 1 -> 2 while reading 5
receiving storage event 2 -> 3 while reading 5
receiving storage event 3 -> 4 while reading 5
receiving storage event 4 -> 5 while reading 5
receiving storage event 0 -> 2 while reading 10
receiving storage event 2 -> 4 while reading 10
receiving storage event 4 -> 6 while reading 10
receiving storage event 6 -> 8 while reading 10
receiving storage event 8 -> 10 while reading 10
```

It appears that:

- In both browsers, concurrent modifications only become visible once the current task has finished executing, not during the task. If two tasks read and write concurrently, they don't see each other, but overwrite each other's work.
- In both browsers, it is possible to receive obsolete storage events, i.e. events about a state that has already been overwritten.
- In both browsers, all windows see the events in the same order, and the latest (visible) write wins.
- In Chrome, writes are broadcast to other windows as they occur, while Firefox broadcasts them once the task completes.

Comment: Can you give more detail on "*Earlier versions of the WebStorage spec*", please? When is the mutex acquired and when is it released?

Comment: Thanks, perfect! You might want to quote the "*the length attribute of a Storage object and the value of the various properties of that object, cannot change while a script is executing, other than […] by the script itself.*" part in the answer itself

Comment: @meriton I want to accept your answer and give bounty to you, because your answer was the most helpful(because it provided links to standards), but I think it is not complete. Can you add my code(which I added to question) to implementation in current browsers, so that it would help other users?

Comment: I wouldn't want to take credit for your work, feel free to post your test code as a separate answer.

Comment: How does the snippet prove it's a mutex? FWIW I don't see consistent results in Chrome and Firefox, but from my tests, which does lock page A into checking the saved value is still the one that's been set before the busy loop, and at the same time set new values from page B, and listens for changes on page C, I get that the object page A has access to isn't updated during the busy loop, like you. But, page C does see the changes made by page B. So I don't think it's really a mutex, it's more that each page has its own version of the Storage object and it gets synced at different times.

Comment: In Chrome it's updated before the busy loop. In Firefox it seems to be updated at the end of the task. What would be interesting in your test is to check what's the value of `localStorage.test` when you receive the *storage* event: should still be `"30"` if it was really a mutex and your second tab was waiting.

Comment: @Kaiido: You're right, Firefox is different. I missed that because most of my tests in firefox were with an earlier, slightly simpler test code, where the difference was too subtle to spot :-(  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Your snippet still doesn't prove it's using a mutex in Chrome. Once again, add a check in the first tab's  `onstorage` event to see what's the stored value. It will be `"10"`, i.e the last value set by that very page, even though your second tab did update it at some point. I set up a more thorough test in [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77985742/3702797).

Comment: I have, and it says "30". And the timing strongly hints at a mutex, too, because the script in the second tab, in spite of doing only a single read and write to localStorage, takes several seconds to return.

Comment: Are you sure you are running both tabs in their own agent? Sounds like they are running on the same thread, and so what you are seeing is just the JS execution being locked until the first page is free.

Comment: Today I learned that the "New Tab" pages of separately launched chrome browser windows actually share the same os process and javascript engine. Ok, will test again with better methodology.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage

## Can 2 be stored before 1?

Javascript uses a single thread and executes the commands sequentially. So, if you have

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 1);
localStorage.setItem('key', 2);
```

then my expectation would be that 1 is stored before 2 and 2 overrides 1, because `setItem` seems to be a simple function call and I don't think it is involving async data. I am saying "I don't think" because I do not know where its source-code is, but given the fact that it's native code:

[image]

it's up to the browser developers to implement it or integrate an implementation. I understand you want to factually find this out, so here's a test:

```
let one = 0;
let two = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    localStorage.setItem('key', 1);
    localStorage.setItem('key', 2);
    if (localStorage.getItem('key') == 1) one++;
    else two++;
}
console.log('one ' + one + ' two ' + two);
```

Output in FireFox:

> one 0 two 10000

and the same in Chrome. So the answer is **no**.

## Can 3 or 4 be stored between 1 and 2?

If Javascript in two different tabs can run at the same time, then yes. Let's write a test for that:

```
setTimeout(function() {alert("the other tab")}, 5000);
```

Run this code in a tab and quickly drift away to another tab. If in 5 seconds you see an alert while you are on the other tab, then the answer is yes. If not, then the answer is no. Running this in FireFox and drifting to another tab, I can see a red dot appearing on the now inactive tab, signifying that the alert happened there. The same happened at Chrome, but there the dot was orange. So the answer is **yes**.

## Can tab_3 receive storage events not in same order as values were stored in?(like if we stored 3, 4, 1, 2, can we receive 1, 2, 3, 4, or even in random order like 4, 1, 2, 3)

This largely depends on the implementation, but I expect the loading of the data stored in `localStorage` to be behaving in the same manner upon each call. You can test it by running your codes in tab1 and tab2, respectively, possibly using `setTimeout` and opening further tabs, either before or after running your codes and check the value of `localStorage` in each. If they are the same, then the test's result suggests that it is reliable indeed. If not, then the test disproved my hypothesis about reliability.

Comment: Tests like these can only provide anecdotal evidence, there is no reliability

Comment: @Bergi how would you test instead this on a browser?

Comment: Point is I *wouldn't* "test" this. I would look through the spec and browser implementation notes. Only those can provide guarantees. Race conditions are not prevented by being lucky.

Comment: @Bergi do you think that the notes are always accurate and reliable?

Comment: I see no reason to distrust them (other than aging). Sure you can also study the code itself if you feel the need for it.

Comment: @Bergi I trust information tested than nontested information. Reading the implementation notes of the browser will tell you what the intention was. But I sure trust more any such information if they are confirmed by tests.

Comment: Testing can be used to show the presence of bugs, but not to prove their absence - in particular when attempting to expose race conditions that are very hard to reproduce. And tests cannot tell you anything about what the intentional behaviour is.

Comment: @Bergi the question refered to how browsers behave. You advocate reading the implementation notes to find that out. I have no objection to that at all. But I take any such description with a grain of salt and I actually test how it works if I want to find out how it works. I rely much more on what behavior I see rather than how it ought to be based on a description. I did not advocate not reading implementation notes, nor did I advocate "proving bugs". We speak about finding out how a browser behaves. And I tend to believe what I see.

Comment: @Bergi furthermore, if such tests are implemented and automated, then one can test multiple browsers and multiple versions of browsers with the same test rather than having to read the implementation notes for each and every version of every browser. So, some version claims that X is the behavior, but, in the next version it changes even with the devs knowing about it or not. Either with the implementation notes telling you about it or not. And I find reading the source-code of a browser ineffective.

Comment: @Bergi when you claim that there could some race conditions that are difficult to reproduce and they are not covered by the test, then I surely agree. There might always be behaviors we do not know about or do not anticipate. But, once we realize of such behaviors, we can implement a new test case. This is how knowledge grows. Having to read the implementation notes of each browser and each version of each browser and then assuming that to be accurate is simply not very ideal in my opinion. I would consider that to be blind belief and I would confirm any such description with tests.

Comment: "*I would confirm any such description with tests*" - oh there's noting wrong with that. I agree it increases confidence, and allows discovering misbehaviour. But first you need to know what to test for, and which rare edge cases need to be considered! Anecdotes of how it *often* behaves don't help with that.

Comment: @Bergi that's a straw man. Nobody said that we are to use anecdotes, except you. My position was that we can check how the browsers behave. No more, no less. I did not present my thoughts as anything else than practical experimentation. If the tests do not cover a case, then the solution is that once that becomes clear, add a test accordingly. So whenever a new browser version appears automated tests can be executed to confirm whether our expectation (still) fulfills the test. The test does not prove that everything works according to them, but strengthens the case for it.

Comment: @Bergi this is how and why automated tests are being used in the first place. They automatically check whether all the scenarios earlier identified as worthy for checking fulfill the expectation. Of course, there might be unexplored cases or even edge cases, but this is true for every single project and feature where we are to use automated tests. And automated tests are not anecdotes. They are direct results of experiments. Anecdotes are usually unproven heard information. The tests **prove** that the tested scenario behaves in a certain way.

Comment: @Bergi surely, some scenarios might be missed from tests, but that's not an "anecdote", but a missed test case. The solution for missed test cases is to cover them. I'm not even sure what your position is. As I never said that a finite amount of test-cases prove that everything was covered.

Comment: "*Nobody said that we are to use anecdotes, except you. My position was that we can check how the browsers behave.*" - and once you have checked it, all you have is an anecdote about how it did behave that one time. You have not gained any understanding of how it is supposed to work, which is what the OP is asking for. Just like an answer to the question "What range of values does `Math.random()` return?" cannot be obtained by testing. You can run it once, you can run it a thousand times, you can run it every time a new browser version is released. You won't know whether it may ever return 0.

Comment: @Bergi you can run `Math.random()` a hundred times. Or a thousand times. And you will **very likely** experience that there is a variance in the results. Which proves the volatility. Now, if you test a behavior 100 or 1000 times and you reliably always get the same results, then it would be unwise to suspect that there is variance. Maybe I'm a superstitious person, but once the same scenario ran 1000 times with the same results and if it is executed each time a new browser version appears and you never see anything contradicting it, nor reports, then I believe it to be true.

Comment: Well there **is** volatility in storage events.

Comment: @Bergi yes. But when you want to find out whether that volatility manifests in a particular behavior or not, then you can test it repeatedly. If that volatility fails to manifest, then it's likely not there. If it's never manifesting for the particular behavior discussed here, then it's simply not there. Surely, unexpected issues may happen, like your browser crashing or some files being damaged, but repeated tests without counter-example without contradictory reports are fairly reliable.

Comment: "*If that volatility fails to manifest, then it's likely not there*" - no. You just can't know from testing alone. It may be very rare, but would still need to be accounted for. You can learn about that only from the spec/docs, and then you can try to provoke it in a test.